# text doesnot display when trying to replace a string in a pdf using PDFBOX

Tags: pdfbox

I tried to replace a String with "XXX" in the existing pdf, using Apache PDFBOX. I was not able to replace it, when i had directly used the ReplaceString.java present in org.apache.pdfbox.examples.pdmodel

So we modified the following part.

.
.
.

```
      else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                    {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                        {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                            if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                            {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                String string = cosString.getString();
                                string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                cosString.reset();
                                cosString.append( string.getBytes() );
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

.
.
.

Modified as:

```
        else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                    {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                        {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                            if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                            {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                byte[] cosBytes = cosString.getBytes();
                                String s = new String(cosBytes, "Cp1047");
                                if(s.contains(strToFind))
                                 {
                                   String newString = s.replaceAll(strToFind, message);
                                   cosString.reset();
                                   cosString.append( newString.getBytes("Cp1047") );
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

.
.

This replaced the string with another. But in some positions of the PDF, the strings are replaced when given numerics but shows blank when replaced with alphabets.

Please help.